# Button click counter (increment and save)

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help :

The scenario is when the **user1** click the `button` it will increment

Example : **user1** clicks 5 times and then the **user2** when it clicks the next number will be 6. and then when the user1 click again it will be 7
i think it works with ajax and save to db, anyone can help me how to do it. Im a begginer in ajax and database
Here is the code i just know:

```
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" onClick="counter()">Next</button>
<p>Number: <a id="counter">0</a></p>

 </body>
 </html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var counter= 0;
 function counter() {
    counter += 1;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: if you have multiple user at multiple platform then use ajax and store increment value in DB

Comment: As @BilalAhmed said you need some sort of persistence. Either use ajax and a DB or (in this case much easier) use HTML5s `localStorage` (see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: You can't do this with simple HTML and Javascript

Comment: thanks for the info, im still learning how to use ajax.im not a pro but i want to improve my skills in programming

Answer (score 0):

> Please use session storage to store the incremental values.

like store the values using  `sessionStorage.setItem("userclicks",variablevalue);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

       <script type="text/javascript">

           function load()
           {
           if(localStorage.getItem("counter")!=null)
                 {
                     counter = Number(localStorage.getItem("counter"));
                     document.getElementById("counterValue").innerHTML = counter;
                 }

           }
         var counter= 0;        

         function counterFn() {          
            counter = Number(localStorage.getItem("counter"));

            console.log(counter);
            counter += 1;
            localStorage.setItem("counter",counter);             
            document.getElementById("counterValue").innerHTML = counter;
         }

       </script>


    </head>
    <body onload="load();">

    <button type="button" onclick="counterFn()">Next</button>

    <p>Number:<a id="counterValue">0</a></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

       <script type="text/javascript">

           function load()
           {
           if(localStorage.getItem("counter")!=null)
                 {
                     counter = Number(localStorage.getItem("counter"));
                     document.getElementById("counterValue").innerHTML = counter;
                 }

           }
         var counter= 0;        

         function counterFn() {          
            counter = Number(localStorage.getItem("counter"));

            console.log(counter);
            counter += 1;
            localStorage.setItem("counter",counter);             
            document.getElementById("counterValue").innerHTML = counter;
         }

       </script>


    </head>
    <body onload="load();">

    <button type="button" onclick="counterFn()">Next</button>

    <p>Number:<a id="counterValue">0</a></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And how is it supposed to support multi-users?